# Link to specific stdc++ library

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

I have a c++ application which I am trying to build under Linux, it needs to be linked to a third party shared library, however this library has been built with a quite recent version of GCC/glibc (4.8.3/2.18). When I try and build my application using a less recent version of GCC/glibc (4.4.7/2.12), the linked phase of the build fails, with ld complaining of undefined references, which are references to functions defined in the newer libstdc++.

The third party has given me a precompiled version of libstdc++ and libgcc_s to use with the library, but how do I use these versions in my build?

How do I tell GCC to use the precompiled libraries instead of the system ones, while still using the system GCC?

I have tried using the "-nodefaultlibs" option and including "-lstdc++" and "-L" options, but it seems to have no effect on the undefined references.

Example of an error I get during linking:

`undefined reference to std::__throw_bad_function_call()@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
undefined reference to std::length_error::~length_error()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'`

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer, but you may want to push hard to get a build against your version (*and* with your compiler version) to tide you over for now, and seriously consider finding an alternate third-party library, if available, for the future. At a glance it seems like they made a classic design mistake of passing std objects (like exceptions) across library boundaries. This will ultimately become absolute hell for your development and distribution process, especially if your project involves other dependencies.

Comment: By the way, it generally isn't enough to change just the library itself, you'd also have to ensure you're including the exact corresponding stdc++ headers, so that the templated stuff also matches.

Comment: What you are doing should work. Try passing `-v` to see exactly how gcc is invoking the linker.

Comment: @Nemo It would not necessarily work if the matching headers aren't also being used, e.g. things like `~length_error()` can be defined inline in one version but not in another.

Comment: @JasonC: I believe just changing the library should work assuming (a) it's a dynamic library and (b) the major number is the same, because otherwise older binaries would not run on new systems. This is why you see symbols with versioning information (like `@@GLIBCXX_3.4.14`) in their names. Although I agree this is poor practice.

Comment: Wouldn't that work to link against the precompiled lib they've given you like it's an external lib? I think that as long as there's no std stuff that cross the lib to get into the client code, this should be fine. We're having the same problem here with Qualcomm Augmented Reality library which has dependency against libstdc++, while we can only link (because XCode) against libc++.

Comment: (Unrelated to my comments above.) Most recently I had a similar issue with a beta third-party CANopen library. Initially the only reliable solution we found was to update our compiler to match the library build precisely; but this wasn't feasible for ongoing development. Eventually we had to find a different library (which was unfortunate, because the original library's author offered us a free beta, and full CANopen implementations tend to be pricey).

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! Unfortunately I think we're pretty much forced to use this library at this point, but it's a dynamic library at least, I'll need to try a few more things I reckon before I press the library maker to give us a special version. It sounds like it's possible to use their pre-compiled versions then, I'll look at the build options I'm using again as that's probably at fault. I had a quick look at how we're using the library and it doesn't look like we're passing std objects across the library, so hopefully that's one less thing to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the application to build successfully by specifying the full path of the libstdc++ and libgcc_s shared objects in the objects list of the linking command (e.g. /home/mike/Downloads/libstdc++.so.6) . Going this way I didn't need to use any additional options such as "-nostdlibs" and only needed to ensure the linked shared objects were available via the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when running the application.